# libc++abi installation osx problems

Tags: macos, libc++

I'm trying to install [libc++abi](http://libcxxabi.llvm.org/) (in order to install [libc++](http://libcxxabi.llvm.org/)) on Mac OSX 10.6.8.

The installer gives the error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:49 (message):
llvm-config not found and LLVM_MAIN_SRC_DIR not defined.  Reconfigure with
-DLLVM_CONFIG=path/to/llvm-config or -DLLVM_PATH=path/to/llvm-source-root.
```

..to which I respond:

```
$> sudo cmake -DLIBCXXABI_LIBCXX_INCLUDES=path/to/libcxx/include .. -DLLVM_PATH=..

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:59 (message):
Not found: /usr/lib/llvm/projects/libcxxabi/cmake/modules
```

`/cmake` doesn't contain `/modules`.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I've managed to install LLVM 3.5-svn's `libc++abi` on 10.6.8, but not with CMake. I did it by hacking slightly and then running the script `llvm/projects/libcxxabi/lib/buildit`, if I recall correctly, and copying the library into `/usr/lib`. IIRC you had to set `$TRIPLE` to `-apple-`, too.

Comment: Some other details come to mind; I first built LLVM and Clang, then `export`-added the `path/to/installation/directory/bin` to the _front_ of `$PATH`, and exported `CXX=clang++` before invoking `buildit`. The Mac OS X `g++` is quite old and can't handle C++11. _Must_ you use Cmake? I followed the installation instructions for LLVM, Clang, libc++abi and libc++ more-or-less to the letter (using `./configure` and suchlike) and gotten away with it.